# How can add html to div after load page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can add html to div after load page?
This HTML:

```
<div id="information-box"> </div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$("#Step-02").find('#information-box', function () {
  for(i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++) {
    $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').html(
        // HTML
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: wrap your code in `DOM` ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it when the page is loaded... There's a few ways, but the easiest is to use the jquery shorthand for doing so:

```
    $(function(){
       $("#Step-02").find('#information-box', function () {
      for(i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++) {
        $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').html(
            // HTML
        );
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ready method in jQuery which is fired when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Step-02").find('#information-box', function () {
      for(i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++) {
        $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').html(
            // HTML
        );
      }
    })
});
```